# Deny access to html page

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.NET Web Forms project. I created a folder `Demo` in this project and put in this folder `HelloWorld.html`. I need deny access to this **html** (it's important not asp) page for all users. How can I do this?

I tried this way, but it didn't work (but  it works perfectly with asp page).

```
<configuration>
    <location path="Demo/HelloWorld.html">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you not know how to restrict access to HTML pages, or do you not know how to restrict access at all?

Comment: His problem is that the <location> element will not respect *.html files, only *.aspx files, and he's asking how to restrict for *.html files specifically.

Answer (score 7):

Your `web.config` is correct. The problem is this secures files that are going through the ASP.NET pipeline. Certain static files, like `html` files, are served up directly by IIS and so it is bypassing your security.

You can force static files to go through the ASP.NET pipeline by adding a handler for them under the `<system.webServer>` section of your web.config:

```
<handlers>
    <add name="HTMLHandler" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET"  />
</handlers>
```